# Simple code in Lucene 4.1 throwing a NullPointerException

Tags: java, lucene

```
Tokenizer tokenizer 
           = new org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizer
                                    (Version.LUCENE_41,new StringReader("!!!"));
tokenizer.incrementToken();
```

Throws

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.std34.StandardTokenizerImpl34.zzRefill(StandardTokenizerImpl34.java:812)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.std34.StandardTokenizerImpl34.getNextToken(StandardTokenizerImpl34.java:1019)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizer.incrementToken(StandardTokenizer.java:180)
```

This code was working okay with Lucene 36, why is it thorweing an exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same problem as you (i.e. NullPointerException after upgrading to 4.1 from 3.6), although I am using a `org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream`. After digging around in the Lucene source, I found that calling the `reset` method before calling `incrementToken` addresses the issue.

You can have a look at the documentation for the previous version here:

https://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardTokenizer.html#reset(java.io.Reader)

Comment: Thanks this was the solution

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you replaced the text passed to the StringReader in your production code when you posted it here, but `"!!!"` seems like something that could lead to odd behavior to me.  Since the string is entirely punctuation, I don't believe there are any tokens there for it to consume.  I'm honestly not sure what `.incrementToken()` should do when called with an input that has no tokens in it.

Have you tried it using an input with valid tokens?

Comment: Sure, it sholdn't create a token but incrementToken() should just return false not throw an exception, the point is this testcase works with Lucene 3.6